# multiple keys for a map in C++

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a table where the entries are something like this

```
Row - Column1 - Column2 - Column3 Column4

 1     0X0A      1          2      A
 2     0X0B      2          2      B
 3     0x0C      3          2      C
```

Now i want to use map in such that i can use column 1 or Column 2 as the key to get the row.
What kind of map i should use to achieve this?

(Note- Table is just for explanation and not the exact requirement) 
I thought of using multimap, but that is not going to solve the prob

Comment: I assume you do not always have such a nice correlation between col 1 & 2? Obviously, right now, following that pattern, you just need a bit a math to convert the value in col 1 to col 2. Is the correlation between 1 and 2 random, or deterministic?

Comment: boost has a multimap however assuming these key values are unique why not just have a second map of column 2 to column 1 so you can always look up the row by column 1?

Answer (score 8):

try multi-index containers from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Define a class similar to `pair` with a custom comparator that indicates equality if either the first member or the second member match, but not necessarily both. You could then use that class as your key type. You would probably need a particular value for each member that will never be used in your data, to use as default values in your constructor, to avoid keys where only the first member has been initialized occasionally matching on the second member due to leftover data.

Comment: is like having actually 2 maps in a single map (any line will have 2 entries in the map)?

Comment: You could do it either way, I guess, but I was thinking of just a single entry under e.g. `mykey(val1, val2)`, but then you could look up an entry with `mykey(val1, default)` or `mykey(default, val2)`. Entering each value twice with the two keys just makes your map take twice as much memory.

Comment: will not work for a stl map. The comparator requested by the map key is a less function. It is impossible to define a less function for this problem!

Comment: Nicolae Dascalu, the following purports to accomplish what you say is impossible:  http://cnx.org/content/m35767/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You could use one map to map from column 1 to the row and another to map from column 2 to the row.  Repeat for as many columns as needed