# Map supporting multiple keys for each value in c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I'm looking for either a ready made associative map container that supports multiple keys (aliases) that map to a single value.

If there's no ready made solution, am I likely to have to resort to using 2 separate maps or is there a better way?

It seems the std::multimap is the reverse of what I want.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087068/multiple-keys-for-a-map-in-c) that is much the same has an accepted answer of boost::multi_index, but I've had a look at the documentation and am completely baffled on how to use it.

If the multi_index can help me implement this, does anyone have an example??

Comment: The first boost example doesn't help? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/example/basic.cpp from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html

Comment: `boost::multi_index` is to be used when your keys are of several types, example, `int` and `std::string`. As I understand you question, your keys have only one type, and you want 2 keys to point to the same data, which is not the same as having multi_index.